# Cherrypy Error While Building in Fedora 28

Tags: python, linux, fedora, cherrypy

So I am new to fedora and have been trying to build a piece of software called Graphical Forecast Editor or GFE from SourceForge, but while trying to get ifpServer running, I came across a cherryp python module error. Can anyone help me out with this? I should also note, I've been trying to figure out how to get the module cherrypy by running "pip install cherrypy", but I get "requirement already satisfied" in so-and-so folders. Hoping for a response and an easy fix.

```
[tony@localhost ~]$ cd Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/bin/
[tony@localhost bin]$ ls
gfe gfei ifpServer run
[tony@localhost bin]$ ./ifpServer -t
IFPDaemon.C 76 EVENT: ==== IFP Data Server Starting ====
IFPDaemon.C 77 EVENT: Version: Version: 1.12.0 March/02/2020
Build date: Tue Mar 3 05:50:33 2020, by: tony, on: localhost.localdomain (linux)
IFPDaemon.C 368 EVENT: Checking for server configuration python errors
IFPDaemon.C 401 EVENT: Loading server configuration: serverConfig...
IFPDaemon.C 423 EVENT: serverConfig loaded.
IFPDaemon.C 535 EVENT: Scanning file system for owner/group permissions
IFPDaemon.C 545 EVENT: Scanning completed
IFPDaemon.C 107 EVENT: Creating services...
MapManager.C 156 EVENT: MapManager started.
configureTextProducts.py 505 EVENT: Configuring Text Products Begin........
configureTextProducts.py 571 EVENT: Configuration of Text Products Finish
createComboAreaDict.py 453 EVENT: Configuring Text Combo Files and Dictionaries Begin Site= BOU
createComboAreaDict.py 225 EVENT: Generating AreaDictionary
createComboAreaDict.py 459 EVENT: Configuring Text Combo Files and Dictionaries Finish
MapManager.C 237 EVENT: MapManager ready.
IFPGridDatabase.C 189 PROBLEM: DatabaseFAIL: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/data/databases/BASE/GRID/Official/BOU_GRID__Official_00000000_0000.cdf
DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 960 PROBLEM: Database invalid with id: BOU_GRID__Official_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 961 PROBLEM: DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 962 PROBLEM: Deleting bogus database: BOU_GRID__Official_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__Official_00000000_0000.HistoryStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__Official_00000000_0000.cdf
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__Official_00000000_0000.KeyStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 951 PROBLEM: Attempting to recreate: BOU_GRID__Official_00000000_0000
IFPGridDatabase.C 189 PROBLEM: DatabaseFAIL: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/data/databases/BASE/GRID/Official/BOU_GRID__Official_00000000_0000.cdf
DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 960 PROBLEM: Database invalid with id: BOU_GRID__Official_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 961 PROBLEM: DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 962 PROBLEM: Deleting bogus database: BOU_GRID__Official_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__Official_00000000_0000.HistoryStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__Official_00000000_0000.cdf
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__Official_00000000_0000.KeyStorageArea
IFPGridDatabase.C 189 PROBLEM: DatabaseFAIL: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/data/databases/BASE/GRID/Fcst/BOU_GRID__Fcst_00000000_0000.cdf
DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 960 PROBLEM: Database invalid with id: BOU_GRID__Fcst_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 961 PROBLEM: DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 962 PROBLEM: Deleting bogus database: BOU_GRID__Fcst_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__Fcst_00000000_0000.cdf
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__Fcst_00000000_0000.HistoryStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__Fcst_00000000_0000.KeyStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 951 PROBLEM: Attempting to recreate: BOU_GRID__Fcst_00000000_0000
IFPGridDatabase.C 189 PROBLEM: DatabaseFAIL: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/data/databases/BASE/GRID/Fcst/BOU_GRID__Fcst_00000000_0000.cdf
DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 960 PROBLEM: Database invalid with id: BOU_GRID__Fcst_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 961 PROBLEM: DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 962 PROBLEM: Deleting bogus database: BOU_GRID__Fcst_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__Fcst_00000000_0000.cdf
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__Fcst_00000000_0000.HistoryStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__Fcst_00000000_0000.KeyStorageArea
IFPGridDatabase.C 189 PROBLEM: DatabaseFAIL: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/data/databases/BASE/GRID/Fcst/BOU_GRID_Prac_Fcst_00000000_0000.cdf
DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 960 PROBLEM: Database invalid with id: BOU_GRID_Prac_Fcst_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 961 PROBLEM: DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 962 PROBLEM: Deleting bogus database: BOU_GRID_Prac_Fcst_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID_Prac_Fcst_00000000_0000.KeyStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID_Prac_Fcst_00000000_0000.HistoryStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID_Prac_Fcst_00000000_0000.cdf
GridParmMgr.C 951 PROBLEM: Attempting to recreate: BOU_GRID_Prac_Fcst_00000000_0000
IFPGridDatabase.C 189 PROBLEM: DatabaseFAIL: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/data/databases/BASE/GRID/Fcst/BOU_GRID_Prac_Fcst_00000000_0000.cdf
DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 960 PROBLEM: Database invalid with id: BOU_GRID_Prac_Fcst_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 961 PROBLEM: DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 962 PROBLEM: Deleting bogus database: BOU_GRID_Prac_Fcst_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID_Prac_Fcst_00000000_0000.KeyStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID_Prac_Fcst_00000000_0000.HistoryStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID_Prac_Fcst_00000000_0000.cdf
IFPGridDatabase.C 189 PROBLEM: DatabaseFAIL: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/data/databases/BASE/GRID/Fcst/BOU_GRID_Test_Fcst_00000000_0000.cdf
DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 960 PROBLEM: Database invalid with id: BOU_GRID_Test_Fcst_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 961 PROBLEM: DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 962 PROBLEM: Deleting bogus database: BOU_GRID_Test_Fcst_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID_Test_Fcst_00000000_0000.HistoryStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID_Test_Fcst_00000000_0000.KeyStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID_Test_Fcst_00000000_0000.cdf
GridParmMgr.C 951 PROBLEM: Attempting to recreate: BOU_GRID_Test_Fcst_00000000_0000
IFPGridDatabase.C 189 PROBLEM: DatabaseFAIL: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/data/databases/BASE/GRID/Fcst/BOU_GRID_Test_Fcst_00000000_0000.cdf
DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 960 PROBLEM: Database invalid with id: BOU_GRID_Test_Fcst_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 961 PROBLEM: DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 962 PROBLEM: Deleting bogus database: BOU_GRID_Test_Fcst_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID_Test_Fcst_00000000_0000.HistoryStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID_Test_Fcst_00000000_0000.KeyStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID_Test_Fcst_00000000_0000.cdf
IFPGridDatabase.C 189 PROBLEM: DatabaseFAIL: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/data/databases/BASE/GRID/LAPS/BOU_GRID__LAPS_00000000_0000.cdf
DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 960 PROBLEM: Database invalid with id: BOU_GRID__LAPS_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 961 PROBLEM: DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 962 PROBLEM: Deleting bogus database: BOU_GRID__LAPS_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__LAPS_00000000_0000.HistoryStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__LAPS_00000000_0000.cdf
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__LAPS_00000000_0000.KeyStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 951 PROBLEM: Attempting to recreate: BOU_GRID__LAPS_00000000_0000
IFPGridDatabase.C 189 PROBLEM: DatabaseFAIL: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/data/databases/BASE/GRID/LAPS/BOU_GRID__LAPS_00000000_0000.cdf
DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 960 PROBLEM: Database invalid with id: BOU_GRID__LAPS_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 961 PROBLEM: DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 962 PROBLEM: Deleting bogus database: BOU_GRID__LAPS_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__LAPS_00000000_0000.HistoryStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__LAPS_00000000_0000.cdf
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__LAPS_00000000_0000.KeyStorageArea
IFPGridDatabase.C 189 PROBLEM: DatabaseFAIL: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/data/databases/BASE/GRID/SAT/BOU_GRID__SAT_00000000_0000.cdf
DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 960 PROBLEM: Database invalid with id: BOU_GRID__SAT_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 961 PROBLEM: DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 962 PROBLEM: Deleting bogus database: BOU_GRID__SAT_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__SAT_00000000_0000.KeyStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__SAT_00000000_0000.HistoryStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__SAT_00000000_0000.cdf
GridParmMgr.C 951 PROBLEM: Attempting to recreate: BOU_GRID__SAT_00000000_0000
IFPGridDatabase.C 189 PROBLEM: DatabaseFAIL: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/data/databases/BASE/GRID/SAT/BOU_GRID__SAT_00000000_0000.cdf
DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 960 PROBLEM: Database invalid with id: BOU_GRID__SAT_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 961 PROBLEM: DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 962 PROBLEM: Deleting bogus database: BOU_GRID__SAT_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__SAT_00000000_0000.KeyStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__SAT_00000000_0000.HistoryStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__SAT_00000000_0000.cdf
IFPGridDatabase.C 189 PROBLEM: DatabaseFAIL: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/data/databases/BASE/GRID/MSAS/BOU_GRID__MSAS_00000000_0000.cdf
DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 960 PROBLEM: Database invalid with id: BOU_GRID__MSAS_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 961 PROBLEM: DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 962 PROBLEM: Deleting bogus database: BOU_GRID__MSAS_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__MSAS_00000000_0000.cdf
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__MSAS_00000000_0000.HistoryStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__MSAS_00000000_0000.KeyStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 951 PROBLEM: Attempting to recreate: BOU_GRID__MSAS_00000000_0000
IFPGridDatabase.C 189 PROBLEM: DatabaseFAIL: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/data/databases/BASE/GRID/MSAS/BOU_GRID__MSAS_00000000_0000.cdf
DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 960 PROBLEM: Database invalid with id: BOU_GRID__MSAS_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 961 PROBLEM: DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 962 PROBLEM: Deleting bogus database: BOU_GRID__MSAS_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__MSAS_00000000_0000.cdf
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__MSAS_00000000_0000.HistoryStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__MSAS_00000000_0000.KeyStorageArea
IFPGridDatabase.C 189 PROBLEM: DatabaseFAIL: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/data/databases/BASE/GRID/RTMA/BOU_GRID__RTMA_00000000_0000.cdf
DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 960 PROBLEM: Database invalid with id: BOU_GRID__RTMA_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 961 PROBLEM: DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 962 PROBLEM: Deleting bogus database: BOU_GRID__RTMA_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__RTMA_00000000_0000.KeyStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__RTMA_00000000_0000.HistoryStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__RTMA_00000000_0000.cdf
GridParmMgr.C 951 PROBLEM: Attempting to recreate: BOU_GRID__RTMA_00000000_0000
IFPGridDatabase.C 189 PROBLEM: DatabaseFAIL: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/data/databases/BASE/GRID/RTMA/BOU_GRID__RTMA_00000000_0000.cdf
DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 960 PROBLEM: Database invalid with id: BOU_GRID__RTMA_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 961 PROBLEM: DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 962 PROBLEM: Deleting bogus database: BOU_GRID__RTMA_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__RTMA_00000000_0000.KeyStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__RTMA_00000000_0000.HistoryStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__RTMA_00000000_0000.cdf
IFPGridDatabase.C 189 PROBLEM: DatabaseFAIL: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/data/databases/BASE/GRID/Restore/BOU_GRID__Restore_00000000_0000.cdf
DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 960 PROBLEM: Database invalid with id: BOU_GRID__Restore_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 961 PROBLEM: DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 962 PROBLEM: Deleting bogus database: BOU_GRID__Restore_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__Restore_00000000_0000.HistoryStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__Restore_00000000_0000.KeyStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__Restore_00000000_0000.cdf
GridParmMgr.C 951 PROBLEM: Attempting to recreate: BOU_GRID__Restore_00000000_0000
IFPGridDatabase.C 189 PROBLEM: DatabaseFAIL: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/data/databases/BASE/GRID/Restore/BOU_GRID__Restore_00000000_0000.cdf
DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 960 PROBLEM: Database invalid with id: BOU_GRID__Restore_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 961 PROBLEM: DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 962 PROBLEM: Deleting bogus database: BOU_GRID__Restore_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__Restore_00000000_0000.HistoryStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__Restore_00000000_0000.KeyStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__Restore_00000000_0000.cdf
IFPGridDatabase.C 189 PROBLEM: DatabaseFAIL: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/data/databases/BASE/GRID/ISC/BOU_GRID__ISC_00000000_0000.cdf
DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 960 PROBLEM: Database invalid with id: BOU_GRID__ISC_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 961 PROBLEM: DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 962 PROBLEM: Deleting bogus database: BOU_GRID__ISC_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__ISC_00000000_0000.KeyStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__ISC_00000000_0000.cdf
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__ISC_00000000_0000.HistoryStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 951 PROBLEM: Attempting to recreate: BOU_GRID__ISC_00000000_0000
IFPGridDatabase.C 189 PROBLEM: DatabaseFAIL: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/data/databases/BASE/GRID/ISC/BOU_GRID__ISC_00000000_0000.cdf
DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 960 PROBLEM: Database invalid with id: BOU_GRID__ISC_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 961 PROBLEM: DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
GridParmMgr.C 962 PROBLEM: Deleting bogus database: BOU_GRID__ISC_00000000_0000
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__ISC_00000000_0000.KeyStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__ISC_00000000_0000.cdf
GridParmMgr.C 980 PROBLEM: Bad database moved to: /home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/release/BAD/BADDB-20200303_0646-BOU_GRID__ISC_00000000_0000.HistoryStorageArea
GridParmMgr.C 1055 PROBLEM: Database BOU_GRID__Official_00000000_0000 is not valid.
DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.Database BOU_GRID__Fcst_00000000_0000 is not valid.
DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.Database BOU_GRID_Prac_Fcst_00000000_0000 is not valid.
DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.Database BOU_GRID_Test_Fcst_00000000_0000 is not valid.
DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.Database BOU_GRID__LAPS_00000000_0000 is not valid.
DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.Database BOU_GRID__SAT_00000000_0000 is not valid.
DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.Database BOU_GRID__MSAS_00000000_0000 is not valid.
DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.Database BOU_GRID__RTMA_00000000_0000 is not valid.
DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.Database BOU_GRID__Restore_00000000_0000 is not valid.
DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.Database BOU_GRID__ISC_00000000_0000 is not valid.
DBInvalid - DatabaseID construction failure.
TopoMgr.C 50 EVENT: Topography Manager started
TopoMgr.C 72 EVENT: Topography Manager ready
IFPServer.C 121 EVENT: Starting networking...
IFPServer.C 137 PROBLEM: pserver startup: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/ifpServer/server/PyServer.py", line 3, in <module>
from . import WebServer, IrtAccess
File "/home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/ifpServer/server/WebServer.py", line 3, in <module>
from . import restAPI, rpcAPI, NotifyMgr, status, periodic
File "/home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/ifpServer/server/restAPI.py", line 1, in <module>
from . import NotifyMgr, status
File "/home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/ifpServer/server/status.py", line 4, in <module>
from . import WebUtil as wu
File "/home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/ifpServer/server/WebUtil.py", line 1, in <module>
import numpy, tarfile, zipfile, time, cherrypy, re, socket, struct, hashlib, io
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cherrypy'</module></module></module></module></module>

IFPDaemon.C 115 PROBLEM: Failed to start services. Shutting down...
IFPDaemon.C 127 EVENT: IFP Data Server Stopping...
IFPDaemon.C 838 EVENT: Shutdown the system.
IFPServer.C 287 EVENT: Attempting to stop IRT Access
IFPServer.C 294 PROBLEM: irtStop startup: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/ifpServer/server/PyServer.py", line 3, in <module>
from . import WebServer, IrtAccess
File "/home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/ifpServer/server/WebServer.py", line 3, in <module>
from . import restAPI, rpcAPI, NotifyMgr, status, periodic
File "/home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/ifpServer/server/restAPI.py", line 1, in <module>
from . import NotifyMgr, status
File "/home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/ifpServer/server/status.py", line 4, in <module>
from . import WebUtil as wu
File "/home/tony/Downloads/gfe-1.12.0/ifpServer/server/WebUtil.py", line 1, in <module>
import numpy, tarfile, zipfile, time, cherrypy, re, socket, struct, hashlib, io
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cherrypy'</module></module></module></module></module>

IFPDaemon.C 95 EVENT: ==== IFP Data Server Stoped ====
IFPDaemon.C 838 EVENT: Shutdown the system.
```

Comment: `pip3 install ...` maybe?

Comment: `pip3 install cherrypy` might fix it?